# How can I filter node_modules functions out of a javascript stack trace?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, error-handling

When I make one of my frequent errors in js, I get a stack trace of the past 20 or so scopes that the execution of my program has gone through. Each one has a file and line number.

This is extremely useful *so long as functions I've written are shown in that trace...* so long as I can see which one of my functions was last called.

Often times all of the functions in the stack trace are within libraries. This is most commonly the case when I'm working with a framework like React that simply performs many function calls under the hood.

Is there a way to filter out any lines of a stack trace that include *node_modules*? Or, is there a way to show the last few node_modules stack frames, but then skip down to the point in my code where the execution jumped into node_modules functions?

Or am I missing a better way to see javascript errors?